# How to show that the Laurent series of the Riemann Zeta function has $\gamma$ as its constant term?

Tags: integration, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I mean the Laurent series at $s=1$.

I want to do it by proving $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{2t}{(t^2+1)(e^{\pi t}+1)} dt = \ln 2 - \gamma$,

based on the integral formula given in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Integral). But I cannot solve this integral except by using Mathematica. Tried complex analytic ways but no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: You can find a possible approach at [this posting](http://sos440.tistory.com/251) in my blog.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100790/limit-of-zeta-function

Comment: Thanks a lot, @sos440 and David! So I know several ways solving the problem in the title now.

Answer (score 19):

We can show that
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac1{1 - 2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}\tag{1}
$$
converges for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>0$ by applying the [Generalized Dirichlet Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/374428).  To apply the test, we need to show that the partial sum of $(-1)^{n-1}$ is bounded, $|n^{-s}|\to0$, and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}\right|\tag{2}
$$
converges.

When $s\in\mathbb{R}$, $n^{-s}$ head straight from $1$ to $0$, so the sum in $(2)$ is $1$. However, if $s\not\in\mathbb{R}$, then $n^{-s}$ spirals into $0$, and it is not immediately obvious that that spiral has finite length.

Let's look at how $n^{-s}$ spirals into $0$:

$\hspace{6pt}$(a)$\hspace{6pt}$ $\arg(n^{-s}) = -\log(n)\mathrm{Im}(s)$

$\hspace{6pt}$(b)$\hspace{6pt}$ $|n^{-s}| = n^{-\mathrm{Re}(s)} = e^{-\log(n)\mathrm{Re}(s)}$

Thus, $n^{-s}$ lies on the spiral $r = e^{t\theta}$ where the constant
$t = \mathrm{Re}(s)/\mathrm{Im}(s)$.  The length of this curve from $r=1$ to $r=0$ is easily computed to be $|s|/\mathrm{Re}(s)$.  Thus, the total variation of $n^{-s}$, as given in $(2)$, is bounded by $|s|/\mathrm{Re}(s)$, and therefore, the sum in $(1)$ converges.

---

Consider $(1)$ to first order in $s-1$.
$$
\frac1{1 - 2^{1-s}}=\frac1{s-1}\frac1{\log(2)}+\frac12+O(s-1)\tag{3}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}=\log(2)+(s-1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\log(n)}{n}+O\left((s-1)^2\right)\tag{4}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac1{s-1}+\frac{\log(2)}{2}+\frac1{\log(2)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\log(n)}{n}+O(s-1)\tag{5}
$$
Next, we can use the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) to compute
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(k)}{k}=C+\frac{\log(n)^2}{2}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)\tag{6}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}=\log(n)+\gamma+O\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{7}
$$
Then, we can use $(6)$ and $(7)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\log(n)}{n}
&=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log(k)}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(2k)}{2k}\right)\\
&=\small-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(C+\frac{\log(2n)^2}{2}\right)-\left(C+\frac{\log(n)^2}{2}\right)-\log(2)(\log(n)+\gamma)\right)\\
&=\gamma\log(2)-\frac{\log(2)^2}{2}\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(5)$ and $(8)$ yields
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac1{s-1}+\gamma+O(s-1)\tag{9}
$$

Comment: from here, how does one proceed in showing that $\dfrac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \dfrac{1}{1-s} + \gamma + O(s-1)$? Thanks!

Comment: @Eric: $(9)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\log(\zeta(s))
&=\log\left(\frac1{s-1}+\gamma+O(s-1)\right)\\
&=-\log(s-1)+\log\left(1+\gamma(s-1)+O(s-1)^2\right)\\
&=-\log(s-1)+\gamma(s-1)+O(s-1)^2
\end{align}
$$
With proper assumptions on the smoothness of $\zeta$, we can differentiate this to give
$$
\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\frac1{1-s}+\gamma+O(s-1)
$$

Comment: Of course! Please excuse my lack of creativity. =| Thanks for this!!!

Comment: Last question Sir! Could you please give me a quick hint for equation (4)? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Eric: $(4)$ is the Taylor expansion at $s=1$. The constant term is the value at $s=1$: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\log(2)$$ The $(s-1)$ term is the first derivative at $s=1$: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\log(n)}{n}$$ which is computed in $(8)$.

Comment: In the first part, what do you mean by "$n^{−s}$ head straight from 1 to 0"?

Comment: @Henry: When $s\in\mathbb{R}$, $n^{-s}$ follows a straight line (along the real axis) from $1$ to $0$, as opposed to the case where $s\not\in\mathbb{R}$, in which $n^{-s}$ spirals from $1$ to $0$ (which is discussed in the next sentence). Remember we are assuming $\mathrm{Re}(s)\gt0$.

Comment: Rob, this is elegant.  Well done!  -Mark

Answer (score 8):

In [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176834), it is shown that
$$
\zeta(s)=\frac1{s-1}+\gamma+O(s-1)\tag{1}
$$
We can compute more terms of the Laurent expansion using the formula
$$
\begin{align}
(-1)^n\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}s^n}\left[(s-1)\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{k^s}\right]
&=(s-1)\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^n}{k^s}-n\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^{n-1}}{k^s}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Euler-Maclaurin gives
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^n}{k^s}
&=\int_1^m\frac{\log(x)^n}{x^s}\,\mathrm{d}x+c_n(s)+O\left(\frac{\log(m)^n}{m^s}\right)\\
&=\int_0^{\log(m)}x^ne^{(1-s)x}\,\mathrm{d}x+c_n(s)+O\left(\frac{\log(m)^n}{m^s}\right)\\
&=\frac1{(s-1)^{n+1}}\int_0^{(s-1)\log(m)}x^ne^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x+c_n(s)+O\left(\frac{\log(m)^n}{m^s}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since $c_n(s)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\log(k)^n}{k^s}-\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x)^n}{x^s}\,\mathrm{d}x$, we have
$$
c_n'(s)=-c_{n+1}(s)\tag{4}
$$
and since $\frac{\log(x)^n}{x^s}$ increases then decreases for $x\ge1$,
$$
\left|c_n(s)\right|\le2\sup\limits_{x\ge1}\frac{\log(x)^n}{x^s}=2\left(\frac n{es}\right)^n\tag{5}
$$

The left term of $(2)$ is $(s-1)$ times $(3)$
$$
\begin{align}
(s-1)\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^n}{k^s}
&=\frac1{(s-1)^n}\int_0^{(s-1)\log(m)}x^ne^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x+(s-1)c_n(s)\\
&+(s-1)O\left(\frac{\log(m)^n}{m^s}\right)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
The right term of $(2)$ is $n$ times $(3)$ at $n-1$
$$
\begin{align}
n\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^{n-1}}{k^s}
&=\frac{n}{(s-1)^n}\int_0^{(s-1)\log(m)}x^{n-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x+nc_{n-1}(s)+O\left(\frac{\log(m)^{n-1}}{m^s}\right)\\
&=\log(m)^nm^{1-s}+\frac1{(s-1)^n}\int_0^{(s-1)\log(m)}x^ne^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x+nc_{n-1}(s)\\
&+O\left(\frac{\log(m)^{n-1}}{m^s}\right)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Putting $(2)$, $(6)$, and $(7)$ together, we get
$$
\begin{align}
(-1)^n\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}s^n}(s-1)\zeta(s)
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[(s-1)\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^n}{k^s}-n\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^{n-1}}{k^s}\right]\\[6pt]
&=(s-1)c_n(s)-nc_{n-1}(s)\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Evaluating $(8)$ at $s=1$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\left.(-1)^n\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}s^n}(s-1)\zeta(s)\,\right|_{\,s=1}
&=-nc_{n-1}(1)\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[\log(m)^n-n\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^{n-1}}k\right]\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Applying $(9)$, we get the Laurent series for $\zeta(s)$ at $s=1$ to be
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\zeta(s)=\frac1{s-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-s)^n}{n!}\,\gamma_n}\tag{10}
$$
where
$$
\gamma_n=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^n}k-\frac{\log(m)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]\tag{11}
$$

Comment: This was (is) a great supplement to the earlier post!

Answer (score 7):

There is a nice proof in Titchmarsh's "The Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function": putting $\,[x]=\,$ the greatest integer not greater than $\,x\in\mathbb R\,$, we get:
$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\left[\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}\right]\stackrel{\mathbf{(7)}}=\int_1^\infty\frac{[x]-x+\frac{1}{2}}{x^2}\,dx+\frac{1}{2}=\\=\int_1^\infty\frac{[x]-x}{x^2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}+\frac{1}{2}=\int_1^\infty\frac{[x]-x}{x^2}\,dx+1=$$$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\left(\int_m^{m+1}\frac{[x]dx}{x^2}-\int_m^{m+1}\frac{dx}{x}\right)+1\right]=$$$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}m\left(\int_m^{m+1}\frac{dx}{x^2}\right)-\log n+1\right]=$$$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+1-\frac{2}{3}+...+1-\frac{m-1}{m}\right)+1-\log n\right]=$$$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m+1}+1-\log n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{m=1}^n\frac{1}{m}-\log n\right)=:\gamma$$

Finally, since we know $\,\displaystyle{\lim_{s\to 1^+}(s-1)\zeta(s)=1}\,$, we have that $\,s=1\,$ is a simple pole of $\,\zeta(s)\,$ with residue $\,1\,$, so the above gives the free coefficient of the Laurent expansion of $\,\zeta(s)\,$ around $\,1$

**Proof of (7)**: We use the next form of [Abel's summation by parts formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) (all the time, $\,n\in\mathbb N\,$):

**Lemma:** Let $\,\phi(x)\,$ be any function with continuous derivative in $\,[a,b]\,$, then
$$\sum_{a< n\leq b}\phi(n)=\int_a^b\phi(x) dx+\int_a^b\left(x-[x]-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi'(x)dx+\left(a-[a]-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi(a)-\left(b-[b]-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi(b)\,\,\,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\color{blue}{(1)}$$

*$\color{red}{\text{Proof}}$*: Taking $\,a=n\,,\,b=n+1\,$ and integrating by parts we get at once:
$$\int_n^{n+1}\left(x-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi'(x)dx=\left.\left(x-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi(x)\right|_n^{n+1}-\int_n^{n+1}\phi(x)dx=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\phi(n)+\phi(n+1)\right)-\int_n^{n+1}\phi(x)dx\Longrightarrow$$
$$\Longrightarrow \int_n^{n+1}\phi(x)dx+\int^{n+1}_n\left(x-[x]-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi'(x)dx+\left(n-[n]-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi(n)-\left(n+1-[n+1]-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi(n+1)=\phi(n+1)=\sum_{n<m\leq n+1}\phi(m)\,\,,\,\,m\in\mathbb N$$

which shows both that the formula works for the above particular case and that it's enough to check for the case $\,n\leq a<b\leq n+1\,$ , so again integrating by parts:
$$\int_a^b\left(x-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi'(x)dx=\left(b-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi(b)-\left(a-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi(a)-\int_a^b\phi(x)dx$$
Comparing with the equality promised by the lemma, we see the RHS of $\,(1)\,$ above reduces to
$$-\left(b-[b]-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi(b)+\left(b-n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\phi(b)=\left([b]-n\right)\phi(b)$$
and this equals zero *unless* $\,b=n+1\,$, but then the last expression above equals $\,\phi(b)=\phi(n+1)\,$, which is the LHS in $\,(1)\,\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\square$

Now $\,(7)\,$ follows from the above with 
$$a_n=1\,\,,\,\forall n\in\mathbb N\,\,,\,\,\phi(n):=n^{-s}\quad\text{ and }\quad\,\,A(x):=\sum_{0\leq n\leq x}a_n=[x]$$ 
and we get

$$\zeta(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\phi(n)=s\int_1^\infty\frac{[x]dx}{x^{1+s}}$$

Finally, we just write
$$\frac{1}{s-1}=\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^s}$$

Comment: Nice math and nice LaTeX. Hope you had already done this and had it ready, instead of entering it manually.

Comment: Thanks @martycohen. In fact I wrote the above from scratch because of two main reason: (1) I've been fooling a lot around Riemann's zeta function and wanted to clear out to myself some technical stuff in some parts, and (2) I wanted back then to continue practicing my LaTeX skills in this site.

Answer (score 6):

This is my third answer to this question, but I just came up with this much simpler derivation.

---

**A Simple Derivation of the Laurent Series for Zeta**
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1{s-1}+\sum_{k=1}^mk^{-s}-\frac{m^{1-s}-1}{1-s}\tag1\\
&=\frac1{s-1}+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1ke^{(1-s)\log(k)}-\frac{e^{(1-s)\log(m)}-1}{1-s}\tag2\\
&=\frac1{s-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1k\frac{(1-s)^n\log(k)^n}{n!}-\frac{(1-s)^n\log(m)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right]\tag3\\
&=\frac1{s-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-s)^n}{n!}\left[\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^n}k-\frac{\log(m)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: convert powers to exponentials
$(3)$: expand exponentials about $s=1$
$(4)$: pull out a common factor

Taking the limit as $m\to\infty$, for $s\gt1$,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\zeta(s)=\frac1{s-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-s)^n}{n!}\,\gamma_n}\tag5
$$
where
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\gamma_n=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\log(k)^n}k-\frac{\log(m)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]}\tag6
$$
$\gamma_n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ [Stieltjes constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants); $\gamma_0$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

---

**A Rough Bound on the Coefficients**

We can get the following bound on $\gamma_n$ using a truncated version of the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula with $f_n(x)=\frac{\log(x)^n}{x}$
$$
\begin{align}
|\gamma_n|
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^mf_n(k)-\int_1^mf_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left|\,\frac12(f_n(m)+f_n(1))+\int_1^mf_n'(x)\left(\{x\}-\tfrac12\right)\mathrm{d}x\,\right|\\
&\le\frac12[n=0]+\frac12\operatorname*{Var}_{(1,\infty)}(f_n)\\[3pt]
&=\frac{n^n}{e^n}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
$(7)$ guarantees a radius of convergence in $(5)$ of no less than $1$. Since $(s-1)\zeta(s)$ is entire, the radius of convergence of $(5)$ is actually $\infty$.

Comment: It is a fun way to prove that $\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}$ is analytic for $|s-1|< 1$. Usually I do the opposite direction : proving $\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}=\sum_n (n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1}x^{-s}dx)$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > 0$, its Taylor coefficients at $s=1$ are $(-1)^k\gamma_k=\sum_n (n^{-1}(-\log n)^k-\int_n^{n+1}x^{-1}(-\log x)^kdx)$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{2t \over
\pars{t^{2} + 1}\pars{\expo{\pi t} + 1}}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{t \over
t^{2} + 1}\pars{{1 \over \expo{\pi t} + 1} -
{1 \over \expo{\pi t} - 1}}\dd t +
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{t \over
\pars{t^{2} + 1}\pars{\expo{\pi t} - 1}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
-4\ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{t \over
\pars{t^{2} + 1}\pars{\expo{2\pi t} - 1}}\dd t}
_{\ds{-1/2 - \Psi\pars{1} \over 2}}\ +\
\underbrace{2\int_{0}^{\infty}{t \over
\bracks{t^{2} + \pars{1/2}^{2}}\pars{\expo{2\pi t} - 1}}\,\dd t}
_{\ds{\ln\pars{1/2} - {1 \over 2\pars{1/2}} - \Psi\pars{1 \over 2}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\Psi}$ is the
>   [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).
>   $\ds{\Psi\pars{1} = -\gamma}$ where $\ds{\gamma}$ is the *Euler-Mascheroni Constant*. $\ds{\Psi\pars{1 \over 2} = -\gamma - 2\ln\pars{2}}$. In evaluating \eqref{1} I used the
>   [$\ds{\mathbf{\color{black}{6.3.21}}}$ A & S identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm).

\eqref{1} becomes
$$
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{2t \over
\pars{t^{2} + 1}\pars{\expo{\pi t} + 1}}\,\dd t} = \bbx{\ln\pars{2} - \gamma} \approx 0.1159
$$