# $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n \ln n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

How can we compute the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n \ln n}{n}$?

I know it is $\eta '(1)$ , where $\eta$ is the $\eta$ Dirichlet Function , i know its value. But I don't know how to compute it.

An approach I tried is to  expand the series, then gather together the odd  and the even terms  , use $\zeta$ (Riemann's function) and that's all. Then no idea.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I want to compute it... meaning I want to get the result wikipedia says.

Comment: What does Wikipedia say it is?

Comment: It gives the result $\gamma \ln 2- \dfrac{\ln^2 2}{2}$.

Comment: [Here](http://sos440.tistory.com/156)'s a link of sos440's blog article. I think it is quite nice.

Answer (score 13):

This is given in equation $(8)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176834) using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), which says that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(k)}{k}=C+\frac{\log(n)^2}{2}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)\tag{1}
$$
for some constant $C$, and that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k}=\log(n)+\gamma+O\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{2}
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k\frac{\log(k)}{k}
&=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log(2k)}{2k}
-\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log(k)}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\log(k)}{k}+\log(2)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{k}
-\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\log(k)}{k}\\
&=C+\frac{\log(n)^2}{2}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)\\
&+\log(2)\left(\log(n)+\gamma+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\\
&-C-\frac{\log(2n)^2}{2}-O\left(\frac{\log(2n)}{2n}\right)\\
&=\gamma\log(2)-\frac{\log(2)^2}{2}+O\left(\frac{\log(n)}{n}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Let $n\to\infty$ in $(3)$ and we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\log(k)}{k}=\gamma\log(2)-\frac{\log(2)^2}{2}\tag{4}
$$
Note that it doesn't matter what the constant $C$ is, as it gets cancelled out of the calculations.

Comment: and the term $O\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)$ comes from $\frac{\ln(n)}{2n}$. Is it correct? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Ricardo770: Euler-Maclaurin says that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\log(k)}k=\tfrac12\log(n)^2+\frac{\log(n)}{2n}+\gamma_1+\int_n^\infty\left(\{x\}-\tfrac12\right)\frac{\log(x)-1}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ where $\gamma_1=-0.0728158454836767$ is a [Stieltjes constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) and it is not hard to show that for $n\ge5$, $$-\frac{\log(n)-1}{4n^2}\le\int_n^\infty\left(\{x\}-\tfrac12\right)\frac{\log(x)-1}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\le0$$ and $$\gamma_1=\int_1^\infty\left(\{x\}-\tfrac12\right)\frac{1-\log(x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: thank you very much for you reply. I am a bit confused, shouldn´t the last term in the first order E-M be $\int_1^\infty f^\prime(x) P_1(x)\,dx-\int_n^\infty f^\prime(x) P_1(x)\,dx$ , and in this case $f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$. Thank you again.

Comment: @Ricardo770: look at the equation for $\gamma_1$ and the first equation in my previous comment.

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

Let $s>1$. Observe that $$\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n }{n^s}=\frac{1}{2^s}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^s}\tag1$$
and
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}=\frac{1}{2^s}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^s}\tag2$$
then $(1)$ + $(2)$ gives
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n }{n^s}=\left(\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}-1\right)\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}=\left(\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}-1\right)\zeta(s)\tag3$$
where $\zeta(\cdot)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Now differentiating $(3)$ with respect to $s$ gives 
$$\displaystyle -\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n \ln n}{n^s}=\left(-\frac{\ln 2}{2^{s-1}}\right)\zeta(s)+\left(\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}-1\right)\zeta'(s)\tag4$$
 and letting $s$ tend to $1^+$, gives the result:

> $$\displaystyle \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n }{n}\ln n=-\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}+\gamma \ln 2\tag5$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant and where, near $s=1^+$, we have used 
$$\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}= 1- (s-1)\ln 2+(s-1)^2\frac{\ln^2 2}{2}+\mathcal{O}((s-1)^3)$$
together with the Laurent series expansions $$
\begin{align}
\zeta(s) &=\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma+\mathcal{O}(s-1)\\\\
\zeta'(s)&=-\frac{1}{(s-1)^2}+\mathcal{O}(1).\end{align}$$

Comment: The argument in my answer is from an answer to a question that asked why $\gamma$ is the constant term in the Laurent expansion of $\zeta(s)$. We can use that answer to justify the Laurent expansion of $\zeta(s)$ here.

Comment: I believe, however, that the answer should be $\gamma\log(2)-\frac{\log(2)^2}{2}$

Comment: @robjohn Typo fixed. Thanks! Yes, in this answer, I considered the Laurent expansion for $\zeta(s)$ as a known fact.