# How can one evaluate the following series:

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}\frac{(\ln{k})^{2}}{k} \space\space\space ?$$

From [$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n \ln n}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933993/sum-n-geq-1-frac-1n-ln-nn#934347)
it has been answered that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{\ln{k}}{k} = \space \gamma \cdot \ln{2} \space - \space \frac{{(\ln{2})^{2}}}{2} \space \space \space ,  $$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

$ \\ $

Comment: In the answer given by Olivier, maybe try to differentiate (3) one more time?

Comment: Differentiate twice the Eta function and let $z\to 1^+$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. From the standard relation
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n }{n^s}=\left(\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}-1\right)\zeta(s)$$ one may differentiate twice and set $s \to 1^+$ using the Laurent series of the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Laurent_series).

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for replying. From your answer to the other post, when you considered the expansion for  2^(1-s) , isn't the signal preceding the third term positive instead of negative? I'm trying to go through what you've done there together with one additional differentiation.

Comment: @LeonardoBohac You are right, typo has been corrected. Thank you.