# Using Fourier analysis to show a function is positive

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let

$$f(x)=  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i nx}}{n^2+1}$$

on $[-\pi, \pi]$. Prove that $f(x)>0$ for any $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$.

How to use Fourier analysis to show that function is positive? I try to differentiate it, but it seems that the derivative is not convergent. Right?

Answer (score 5):

**Positivity**

Since
$$
\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|}e^{-inx}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac1\pi\frac1{n^2+1}
$$
we have
$$
\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\pi\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-|x+2k\pi|}e^{-inx}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{n^2+1}
$$
Therefore, inverting the transform, we get
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{e^{inx}}{n^2+1}=\pi\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-|x+2k\pi|}
$$

---

**Convergence of the Derivative**

The derivative converges everywhere except for $x\in2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. However, the convergence is only conditional. We can apply the [Generalized Dirichlet Convergence Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/374428) to
$$
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{ine^{inx}}{n^2+1}
$$
since $\frac{in}{n^2+1}$ has bounded variation, tends to $0$ as $|n|\to\infty$, and the partial sums of $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{inx}$ are bounded except where $e^{ix}=1$.

---

**Motivation**

What prompted me to look at $e^{-|x|}$ was to note that the *second* derivative of
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{e^{inx}}{n^2+1}
$$
is
$$
f''(x)=-\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{n^2e^{inx}}{n^2+1}
$$
which does not converge in the standard sense, but in the sense of distributions
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)-f''(x)
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{inx}\\
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(x-2k\pi)
\end{align}
$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta distribution, which is $0$ away from $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. Now, two solutions to $f(x)-f''(x)=0$ are $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$, so this brought to mind $e^{-|x|}$, whose first derivative has a jump discontinuity, which would lead to a Dirac delta distribution at $x=0$.

Adding
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x}e^{-inx}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{1+in}
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0e^xe^{-inx}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{1-in}
$$
gave
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-|x|}e^{-inx}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac2{1+n^2}
$$
which is where I started the first section.

Comment: +1 Just for reference: this is also called [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

Comment: @Fabian: Indeed. This is another way of proving that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{n^2+1}=\pi\coth(\pi)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
f(x)=  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i nx}}{n^2+1}=
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos nx + i\sin nx}{n^2+1}=\cdots
$$
What happens with the imaginary part ($\sin$ is odd)?

Comment: But how does this help to show $f(x)>0$? $\cos(nx)$ can be both positive and negative.

Comment: @Winther, bounding the tail(s) of the series.

Comment: Yes that is the usual approach. However, I tried a simple take out $n=0,1$ and bound $n>2$ using $1/(n^2+1) \leq 1/n^2$ does not seem to be enough.

Comment: @Winther, I will think in it.

Comment: @Winther, T've found a rather convoluted solution. Isn't the same problem, but the recycling is esay. See http://books.google.es/books?id=ceJ38MEM-HAC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=%22fourier+series%22+%22n%5E2%2B1%22&source=bl&ots=N_gQLkgdx2&sig=_aZTbBXctKMJqaOems4aYoE-G7Y&hl=es&sa=X&ei=lQJvVKaCIpDjaryxgbAG&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22fourier%20series%22%20%22n%5E2%2B1%22&f=false

Comment: i have considered in this way:we can reduce the above function to a series of cos.How can we show that the finite term(from -N to N) is positive and large than the infinite term(|n|>N)?

Comment: @mnmn1993, the problem is that the head of the series takes small values near $\pm\pi$ and the series $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}1/(n^2+1)$ (bound of the tail) converges very slowly.

Comment: i find it difficult to show that head of the series takes small values near ±π,can you give some hints?? thanks

Comment: @mnmn1993, draw it with a program.