# Show that $(1-2^{1-z})\zeta(z)=\sum\limits_{s=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^s}{s^z}=$ for Re$(z)>0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Show that $(1-2^{1-z})\zeta(z)=\sum\limits_{s=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^s}{s^z}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\int\limits_{0}^\infty \frac{t^{z-1}}{e^t+1}dt$ for Re$(z)>0$.

Not sure how to get started on this, we have covered some of the formulas for the $\zeta$ function but I don't really have any intuition regarding them.

Comment: see the hint  I wrote there : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746711/alternating-series-test-for-complex-series/1746981#1746981 (Last way)

Comment: I showed that this is true using the Generalized Dirichlet Test in [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746711/alternating-series-test-for-complex-series/1747455#1747455)