# Grouping the Summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

Let $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ and consider $\sum a_n$ and grouping as $\sum (a_n + a_{n+1})$.
 Under what assumptions we can claim absolute convergence of grouped sum implies convergence of the original sum?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746711/alternating-series-test-for-complex-series) is the related post, where accepted answer shows that grouped sum is absolutely convergent.

My concern is, $\sum (-1)^n$ is not convergent where if we group successive terms it is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum |a_n| <\infty$ implies $|a_1-a_2|+|a_3-a_4|+\cdots <\infty$ but the converse is false as seen by taking $a_1=a_2=1, a_3=a_4=\frac 1 2,a_5=a_6=\frac 1 3,\cdots$.

Comment: Is it then true that convergence of $1^{-z} - 2^{-z} + 3^{-z} - \dots$ cannot be showed by arguing $(1-^{-z} - 2^{-z}) + (3^{-z} - 4^{-z}) + \dots$ is absolutely convergent. (As in the first way of accepted answer of linked question)

Comment: You are right. Proving (absolute0 convergence after grouping does nor tell you anything about convergence of the original series.