# Evaluating the Integral: $\int_0^\infty \frac{( \frac{1}{2} - \cos x )}{x} dx$

Tags: calculus

Evaluating the Integral:
$\int_0^\infty\left[\frac{1}{2} - \cos\left(x\right)\right]\,{\rm dx \over x}$

I came upon this limit: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} -Ci(x) + Ci(1/x) +\ln(x)$, is it $\gamma$ ?

Here $ Ci(x) = \gamma + \ln x + \int_0^x \frac{\cos t -1}{t} dt $ is the cosine integral and $\gamma$ is the Euler constant. The Limit and the Integral appear to be equal.

Comment: $$\frac{\frac12-\cos x}{x}$$ has a non-integrable singularity in $0$.

Comment: How about if that 1/2 would be a 1?

Comment: Well the limit gives me this: 0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215933593992359880576723488486772677766467093694706329174674955186905961593475130...

Comment: @Alan Numerically, that is Euler's Constant, $\gamma$

Comment: That looks like Euler's constant!

Comment: @3.1416 : $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\frac1n}^n\frac{\frac12-\cos x}xdx=\gamma$$

Comment: @Alan: Considering the above limit is a completely different matter from "evaluating the integral". We cannot evaluate the integral over the positive real line since $\frac{1/2-\cos x}{x}$ is not Riemann-integrable (in a right neighbourhood of zero, it is bigger than $\frac{1}{3x}$). The same (existence of the above limit without Riemann-integrability) holds for the function $f(x)=\frac{\log x}{x}$, for istance.

Comment: From Mathematica $\large\tt Integrate::idiv: "Integral of       1/(2\x)-Cos[x]/x does not converge on {0.1`,\[Infinity]}"$

Comment: With @Lucian definition, Mathemathica yields $\large\gamma$. So, the OP question was not clearly stated. Every day we learn something new !!!.

Comment: According to @Lucian the result, for a given $\large n$ is $\large {\rm ci}\left(1 \over n\right) - {\rm ci}(n) + \ln(n)$ and the limit $\large n \to \infty$ is $\large \gamma$.

Comment: A similar identity would be $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\frac12-\{x\}}{x^2}dx=\gamma-\frac12$$ which is a special case of the more general identity $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\frac12-\{x\}}{x^{s+1}}dx=\frac{\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}-\frac{1}{2}}s$$ since it is known (don't ask me how or why) that $$\lim_{x\to1}\bigg[\zeta(x)-\frac1{x-1}\bigg]=\gamma.$$

Comment: So, a reference for this would be "Theory of the Riemann Zeta function" by Titchmarsh page 15-16.

Comment: It can be found [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=1CyfApMt8JYC&pg=PA13).

Comment: @Lucian: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3112947) is a quick derivation of the Laurent expansion for $\zeta(s)$ around $s=1$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\left(\frac 1 2 - \cos x\right)\frac {dx} x = \gamma$$

\begin{align*}\int_{1/n}^n \left(\frac 1 2 - \cos x\right)\frac {dx} x &=
\int_{1/n}^1 \left(1 - \cos x\right)\frac {dx} x
-\int_1^n \cos x\frac {dx} x+
\frac 1 2 \left(\int_1^n \frac {dx} x -\int_{1/n}^1 \frac {dx} x\right) \\
&=\int_{1/n}^1 (1-\cos x) \frac {dx} x - \int_1^n \cos x \frac {dx} x
\end{align*}
$$\bbox[0.2ex,border:0.5pt solid black]{\int_0^1 \frac {1-\cos(y)}y\,dy
-\int_1^{+\infty} \frac {\cos(y)} y\,dy=\gamma}$$

Here is the proof of Gronwall, 1918. For $n$ a positive integer
$$\begin{align}
A(n) 
&= \int_0^{n\pi} \frac{1-\cos (y)}{y} dy - \ln ( n\pi ) \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1-\cos (y)}{y} dy + \int_1^{n\pi} \frac{1-\cos (y)}{y} dy - \ln ( n\pi ) \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1-\cos(y)}{t} dy - \int_1^{n\pi} \frac{\cos(y)}{y} dy
\end{align}$$

With a change of variable $x = 2 \pi ny$:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{n\pi} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} xy 
&= \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1 - \cos (2\pi ny)}{y} dy \\
&= \pi \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1 - \cos (2 \pi ny)}{\sin(\pi y)} dy + \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} g(y) dy - \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} g(y) \cos ( 2 \pi ny) dy
\end{align}$$

$g(y) = \frac{1}{y} - \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi y)}$ which is continuous on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ with $g(0) = 0$.

With Riemann-Lebesgue theorem
$$\int_0^\frac{1}{2} g(y) \cos ( 2 \pi n y ) dy \rightarrow 0 \text{ for } n \rightarrow + \infty$$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\frac12 g(y) dy 
&= \lim_{s \to 0^+} \int_s^\frac12 \left( \frac 1y - \frac \pi{\sin(\pi y)} \right) dy \\
&= \lim_{s \to 0^+} \left[ \ln \left( \frac{y}{\tan ( \pi/2\;y )} \right) \right]_s^{\frac{1}{2}} = \ln ( \pi ) - 2 \ln (2)
\end{align}$$

On the other hand
$$\begin{align}
\pi \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1 - \cos ( 2 \pi n y)}{\sin ( \pi y )} dy
&= 2\pi \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin ( (2k-1) \pi y ) dy \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2}{2k-1} 
={\ln (n) + 2 \ln (2) + \gamma + o(1)}
\end{align}$$

Finally
$$A(n) = \gamma + o(1)$$

Thanks very much to Sladjan Stankovik for providing insight into this problem for me.

Comment: There is something suble here. Having $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{1/n}^{n} f(x)\,dx = C$$ *does not* imply that $f(x)$ is a Riemann-integrable function over $\mathbb{R}^+$ with $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = C.$$ @Daniel Fischer is completely right.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: No one said he wasn't... :-) Being able to compute $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=-n}^nk=0$, for instance, is *not* the same thing as saying that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty k$ makes any sense. (Obviously, changing either center of the sum's terms to anything other than $0$, and/or destroying the symmetry of its limits, will yield completely different results).

Comment: @Lucian: we totally agree, I was simply pointing out that the very first line of this answer, strictly speaking, is wrong.

Comment: Reference for the problem : "Euler’s constant with integrals" by Moubinool OMARJEE , Lycée Jean-Lurçat Paris , France -- Twenty-six different integrals that lead to Euler's Constant. (I have no problem with the problem being formulated in a more modern context.) The result of Gronwall is , of course, from 1918.

Comment: @Alan i edited your answer, by converting it to $\TeX$. Can you review it once?

Comment: I agree completely with @JackD'Aurizio last comment. The particular combination $n$ and ${1 \over n}$ cancels each other the logarithmic divergences.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\,\int_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}
     \bracks{\half - \cos\pars{x}}\,{\dd x \over x} = \gamma.\quad}$
$\ds{\quad\gamma}$ is the
[Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant).

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#c00000}{
> \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\,\int_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}\bracks{
> \half - \cos\pars{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}}
> =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\,\bracks{-\int_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}{
> \cos\pars{x} - 1 \over x}\,\dd x - \half\int_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}
> {\dd x \over x}}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\,\braces{
> -\bracks{{\rm Ci}\pars{1 \over \epsilon} - \ln\pars{1 \over \epsilon} - \gamma}
> + \bracks{{\rm Ci}\pars{\epsilon} - \ln\pars{\epsilon} - \gamma}
> -\half\ln\pars{1/\epsilon \over \epsilon}}\tag{1}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{{\rm Ci}\pars{x}}$ is one of the
>   [Cosine Integral Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral).

Expression $\pars{1}$ can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
&\color{#c00000}{
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\,\int_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}\bracks{
\half - \cos\pars{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}}
=\gamma + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\,
\braces{-{\rm Ci}\pars{1 \over \epsilon}
+ \bracks{{\rm Ci}\pars{\epsilon} - \ln\pars{\epsilon} - \gamma}}\tag{2}
\end{align}

> [However](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral)
>   $$
> \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\,{\rm Ci}\pars{1 \over \epsilon} = 0\,,\qquad
> \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\,\,\bracks{
> {\rm Ci}\pars{\epsilon} - \gamma - \ln\pars{\epsilon}} = 0
> $$

such that $\pars{2}$ leads to
$$\color{#00f}{\large
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}\bracks{
\half - \cos\pars{x}}\,{\dd x \over x} = \gamma}
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/n}^n\frac{\frac12-\cos(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(n)-\int_{1/n}^1\frac{\cos(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_1^n\frac{\cos(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\tag{1a}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{1-\cos(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1b}\\
&=\int_0^1(1-\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}\log(x)-\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^{(2n+1)\pi/2}\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}\log(x)\tag{1c}\\
&=-\int_0^1\log(x)\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^{(2n+1)\pi/2}\log(x)\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1d}\\
&=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{(2n+1)\pi/2}\log(x)\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1e}\\
&=-\frac1{2i}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_0^{(2n+1)\pi/2}\log(x)\,e^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{(2n+1)\pi/2}\log(x)\,e^{-ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\tag{1f}\\
&=-\frac1{2i}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(i\int_0^{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi}\!\!\left(\log(x){+}\tfrac{i\pi}2\right)e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x+i\int_0^{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi}\!\!\left(\log(x){-}\tfrac{i\pi}2\right)e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\tag{1g}\\
&=-\int_0^\infty\log(x)\,e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1h}\\[6pt]
&=\gamma\tag{1i}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: break up the integral into pieces
$\text{(1b)}$: reassemble the pieces and evalate the limit
$\text{(1c)}$: write the right hand integral as a limit
$\phantom{\text{(1c):}}$ prepare to integrate by parts
$\text{(1d)}$: integrate by parts
$\text{(1e)}$: combine the integrals
$\text{(1f)}$: $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$
$\text{(1g)}$: [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)
$\text{(1h)}$: evaluate the limits and combine the integrals
$\text{(1i)}$: apply [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2432605)

---

**Contour Integration for $\bf{(1g)}$**

$\newcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$
Step $\text{(1g)}$ above looks like one that is often encountered in contour integration, where the integrand along the "arc at infinity" vanishes sufficiently in absolute value. However, the absolute value of the integrands along both of the arcs at infinity grows like $\log(\Re(z))e^{-|\!\Im(z)|}$. Fortunately, they have opposite signs and cancel to within an error of $O\!\left(\frac1n\right)$. This has the same effect as if the absolute value of the integrand had vanished sufficiently.

[image]

Integrating around the upper-right quadrant, we get the integral along the positive real axis by substituting $z=x$ and the integral along the positive imaginary axis by substituting $z=ix$.

The integral along the arc is a bit more complicated. As the integrand dies away like $e^{-y}$ as $y\to\infty$, we will compute the integral along $\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi+iy$, giving an error of $O\!\left(e^{-x}\right)$.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{2i}\int_{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi}^{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi+i\infty}\log(z)\,e^{iz}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\frac1{2}\int_0^\infty(\log(x)+\log(1+iy/x))\,e^{ix-y}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{i}2(-1)^n\int_0^\infty\left(\log(x)+O(y/x)\right)e^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{2b}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{i}2(-1)^n\log\left(\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\pi\right)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: use $z=x+iy$ where $x=\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$
$\text{(2b)}$: $\log(1+iy/x)=O(y/x)$
$\text{(2c)}$: evaluate the integral

Integrating around the lower-right quadrant, we get the integral along the positive real axis by substituting $z=x$ and the integral along the negative imaginary axis by substituting $z=-ix$.

As the integrand dies away like $e^{-y}$ as $-y\to-\infty$, we will compute the integral along $\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi-iy$, giving an error of $O\!\left(e^{-x}\right)$.
$$
\begin{align}
-\frac1{2i}\int_{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi}^{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi-i\infty}\log(z)\,e^{-iz}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\frac1{2}\int_0^\infty(\log(x)+\log(1-iy/x))\,e^{-ix-y}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{3a}\\
&=-\frac{i}2(-1)^n\int_0^\infty\left(\log(x)+O(y/x)\right)e^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{3b}\\[3pt]
&=-\frac{i}2(-1)^n\log\left(\left(n+\tfrac12\right)\pi\right)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: use $z=x-iy$ where $x=\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$
$\text{(3b)}$: $\log(1-iy/x)=O(y/x)$
$\text{(3c)}$: evaluate the integral

Thus, the sum of the integral along both arcs is $O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\to0$.