# Evaluation of $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}\log\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) \ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I need some hints, clues for getting the closed form of

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}\log\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) \ dx$$

Comment: have you tried u = 1+x?

Comment: Have you tried the sub. $\log(\frac{1}{x})=t$

Comment: I think the following might be of some use
\begin{align*}   I(a)  & = \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+ax)}{1+x}\log \log 1/x\mathrm{d}x \\   I'(a) & = \int_0^1 \frac{x \log \log x}{(ax+1)(x+1)}\mathrm{d}x \\   & = \frac{1}{a-1} \int_0^1 x \log \log \frac 1x\left( \frac{a}{ax+1} - \frac{x}{1+x} \right) \mathrm{d}x \\   & = \frac{1}{a-1} \int_0^1 \log \log \frac 1x\left( \frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{1}{1+ax}\right) \mathrm{d}x \\   & =  \frac{1}{a-1}\frac{\log^2(2)}{2} - \frac{1}{a-1}\int_0^1 \frac{\log \log 1/x}{1+ax}\,\mathrm{d}x   \end{align*}
Then integrate back from 0 to 1, however convergence issuses =/

Comment: [There are](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/issac/issac97.ps) lot of integrals related to the OP question.

Comment: $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\log\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) \ dx = \frac{\pi^2}{12} \left(2 \ln 2 - 12 \ln A + \ln \pi \right),$$ where $A$ is the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant)

Answer (score 16):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x}\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1 \over x}}
     \,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\overbrace{\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x}\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1 \over x}}\,\dd x}}
> ^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\ x \equiv \expo{-t}\ \imp\ t = -\ln\pars{x}}}\ =\ 
> \int_{\infty}^{0}{\ln\pars{1 + \expo{-t}} \over 1 + \expo{-t}}\,\ln\pars{t}\,
> \pars{-\expo{-t}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\mu \to -1}\partiald{}{\mu}\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\expo{-t}
> \pars{1 + \expo{-t}}^{\mu}\,\dd t}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{t}\expo{-t}
\pars{1 + \expo{-t}}^{\mu}\,\dd t}
=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\mu \choose n}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\ln\pars{t}\expo{-\pars{n + 1}t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-\mu + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\partiald{}{\epsilon}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\epsilon}\expo{-\pars{n + 1}t}
\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-\mu + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\partiald{}{\epsilon}
\bracks{{1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{\epsilon + 1}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\epsilon}\expo{-t}\,\dd t}
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-\mu + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\partiald{}{\epsilon}
\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\epsilon + 1} \over \pars{n + 1}^{\epsilon + 1}}}
\\[3mm]&=-\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-\mu + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}\,
{\ln\pars{n + 1} + \gamma \over n + 1}
\end{align}

> Also,
>   $$
> \lim_{\mu \to - 1}\partiald{}{\mu}{-\mu + n - 1 \choose n}
> =-\Psi\pars{n + 1} - \gamma
> $$

such that
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x}\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1 \over x}}\,\dd x}
=-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,
{\bracks{\gamma + \Psi\pars{n}}\bracks{\gamma + \ln\pars{n}} \over n}
\\[3mm]&=-\gamma^{2}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n}
-\gamma\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\ln\pars{n} \over n}
-\gamma\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\Psi\pars{n} \over n}
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\Psi\pars{n}\ln\pars{n} \over n}
\end{align}

> With
>   \begin{align}
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n} & = -\ln\pars{2}
> \\
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\ln\pars{n} \over n}&=
> \gamma\ln\pars{2} - \half\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}
> \\[3mm]
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\Psi\pars{n} \over n}&=
> \gamma\ln\pars{2} + \half\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}
> \end{align}

we'll have
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + x}\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1 \over x}}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large-\gamma^{2}\ln\pars{2}
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\Psi\pars{n}\ln\pars{n} \over n}}
\approx -0.2408
\end{align}

> $\ds{\tt%
> \mbox{So far, I was not able to evaluate the last sum. I'm still trying to}\ldots}$.
>
> It seems related somehow to an
>   [Euler Sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html).

Comment: Could you kindly point me towards a definition of the function $\Psi(n)$? I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: @DavidH   $\displaystyle{\large \Psi\pars{z} \equiv \ln\,'\left(\,\Gamma\left(z\right)\,\right)}$ is the digamma function. You'll find a [good starting point in this table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).

Comment: Got it. As an historical aside, I'm somewhat curious as to the etymology behind labeling the digamma function by the capital Greek letter 'psi' as opposed to, oh I dunno, the Greek letter '[digamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma)'? :) Also, thanks in particular for the reference.

Comment: @DavidH There is some historic report
[over here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma).

Answer (score 6):

Substitute $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ and then $x\mapsto x/n$:
$$
\begin{align}\hspace{-1cm}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x}\log(\log(1/x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+e^{-x})}{1+e^{-x}}\log(x)\,e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_0^\infty(-1)^nH_{n-1}e^{-nx}\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_0^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n-1}}ne^{-x}(\log(x)-\log(n))\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n-1}}n(-\gamma-\log(n))\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Using $(3)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/499689), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n-1}}n
&=\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}n\\
&=\frac12\log(2)^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, we get that $(1)$ is
$$
-\frac\gamma2\log(2)^2-\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n-1}}n\log(n)\tag{3}
$$

---

**Comparison with Felix Marin's Answer**

Using $(8)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176834), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n-1}}n\log(n)
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\psi(n)+\gamma}n\log(n)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\psi(n)}n\log(n)+\gamma^2\log(2)-\gamma\frac{\log(2)^2}{2}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, plugging $(4)$ into $(3)$, we see that $(1)$ is
$$
-\gamma^2\log(2)-\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\psi(n)}n\log(n)\tag{5}
$$
which is the same as Felix Marin gets.

---

**Further Investigation**

Perhaps the next step is to consider the derivative of
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^x}\tag{6}
$$

Comment: @Kirill: that is what I used.