# Does the alternating series converge? [Leibniz criterion]

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Does the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\ln
>  k}{k}$$converge?

**What I have tried:**
It does converge. I applied the Leibniz criterion

1)$$\frac{\ln k}{k}\geq0 \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$$ so the series is indeed alternating.

2)I showed that $$\frac{\ln (k+1)}{k+1}<\frac{\ln k}{k},$$when $k>2$ by introducing function $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ and showing that $f'(x)<0,$ when $x>e$.

3) $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\ln k}{k}=0.$$
The question is: can I ignore the first two terms in part 2) as $$\frac{\ln (k+1)}{k+1}<\frac{\ln k}{k},$$ only when $k>2$?

Comment: it's not defined for $k=0$ ( you wrote $k \in \mathbb{N}$ )

Comment: $k=1,2,3,\dots$

Comment: @Atmos: sources differ. Some have $0\in\mathbb{N}$ and others have $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If you change sequence in only finitely many terms, the series of the first sequence converges if and only if the series of the second sequence converges.

Comment: @robjohn Really ? For the non zero set it is common to use $\mathbb{N}^{*}$ or am I wrong ?

Comment: It is convergent by Leibniz' test and convergent to $\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2)-\gamma\log(2)$ by the reflection formula for the $\zeta$ or $\eta$ function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: this is shown in equation $(8)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176834).

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can "ignore" it. You split out this two terms
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k-1}\frac{\ln\left(k\right)}{k}=0-\frac{\ln(2)}{2}+\sum_{k=3}^{+\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k-1}\frac{\ln\left(k\right)}{k}
$$
So what you've done is good.