# Calculation of the residue of $[-\frac{ζ'(s)}{ζ(s)} \frac{x^s}{s}]$ when s=1

Tags: riemann-zeta

The derivation of Von Mangoldt’s explicit formula $$ψ(x)=x -log⁡(2π)  +∑_n\frac{x^{-2n}}{2n}  -∑_ρ\frac{x^ρ}{ρ}$$
can be achieved by applying the residue theorem to the integral below (Havil's book, p 202)
$$ψ(x)=\frac{1}{2πi}\int_{a-i∞}^{a+i∞}-\frac{ζ'(s)}{ζ(s)} \frac{x^s}{s} ds$$
 $[-\frac{ζ'(s)}{ζ(s)} \frac{x^s}{s}]$ has four singularities: when s is equal to 0 and 1 and when ζ(s) is equal to zero (trivial and non-trivial) and the question is when s=1 how the residue is found to be equal to x?

Answer (score 1):

In the limit $s\to1$ we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}
&=&
\frac{\left(\frac1{s-1}\right)'+O(1)}{\frac1{s-1}+O(1)}
\\
&=&
-\frac{\left(\frac1{s-1}\right)^2+O(1)}{\frac1{s-1}+O(1)}
\\
&=&
-\frac{\frac1{s-1}+O(s-1)}{1+O(s-1)}
\\
&=&
-\frac1{s-1}+O(1)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus the residue of the entire product at $s=1$ is simply minus the value of the remaining factors (which are analytic at $s=1$) at $s=1$, and thus $x$.

Comment: Thanks,  two questions:

Comment: Thanks,  two questions: how did you obtain the remaining of zeta is O(1)? and how did you obtain the derivative of O(1) is also O(1)?

Comment: @Arwashan: You can find the Laurent series of the zeta function in various places on the net, e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Laurent_series) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123531/) on this site. To your second question: The derivative of a function that is $O(1)$ is not necessarily $O(1)$, e.g. consider $\sin\frac1x$. Rather, what I used was that $\zeta(s)-\frac1{s-1}$ is analytic at $s=1$, which implies that it and all its derivatives are $O(1)$ as $s\to1$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But sorry I don't see how zeta(s)-1/(s-1) is analytic at s=1